# Returning date inside plugin

Tags: jquery

I am trying to wrap my head around plugins. The code I am converting is as follows:

```
function parseNum(str) {
    var mdy = str.split('/')
    return new Date(mdy[2], mdy[0]-1, mdy[1]);
}

function daydiff(first, second) {
    return (second-first)/(1000*60)
}


$("#p").text((daydiff(parseNum($('#first').val()), parseNum($('#second').val()))));
```

This is what I have so far

```
;(function ($) {

    $.fn.myPlugin = function (options) {    

        // define defaults
        var defaults = {
            x1: 2/27/2013,
            x2: 2/29/2013
        };

        var o = $.extend(defaults, options);
```

What do I write inside the plugin and how to call it to populate $(#p).text()?

Comment: `2/27/2013` isn't a date, it's a sequence of divisions.

Comment: How do you intend to call the plugin? What are the options `x1` and `x2` supposed to be? How does any of that relate to the code you're trying to replace? Your plugin should take selector arguments, shouldn't it?

Comment: `daydiff` seems to return a difference in minutes, not days.

Comment: And `parseNum` parses a date, not a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write it like this:

```
;(function($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(sel1, sel2) {
        $(this).text(daydiff(parseNum($(sel1).val()), parseNum($(sel2).val()));
    }
}
```

you can do:

```
$("#p").myPlugin('#first', '#second');
```

If you want to be able to enhance your plugin with options, make that a third, optional argument, and use the idiom you wrote to merge it with defaults.